# Change field separator in table

Tags: bash, awk

I have several tables having the following format

```
1971-01-01 1124
1971-01-02 987
1971-01-03 954
...
```

Instead I would like to change the field separator in order to have the following format of table

```
1971 01 01 1124
1971 01 02 987
1971 01 03 954
...
```

Does anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Those `-` characters are part of an ISO 8601 format date, not field separators. You will be removing the ability to parse the date using standard tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tr` (translate) for this:

```
tr -- - ' ' < file
```

`--` indicates that you are not passing any options after that argument. On GNU tr at least, this isn't needed, but it probably is in some other versions.

You can also use `sed` or a whole variety of other tools:

```
sed 'y/-/ /'
awk -F- '$1=$1'  # implicit translation using OFS
```

Answer (score 1):

Tell `awk` to use `-` as a field separator and replace it with a default (space):

```
awk -F - '$1=$1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `sed`

```
$ sed -e 's|-| |g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Several approaches.

```
<file tr \- \ 

<file sed -e 'y/-/ /'

<file awk -F - '{$1=$1};1'

<file perl -pe 'y/-/ /'
```